# summing up of two rows

Tags: sql, plsql

**Input**:

```
A       
-----
 5000      
 4000      
-3000
-2000
```

**Output**:

```
A      FEEDBACK
-----  --------
 9000  POSITIVE
-5000  NEGATIVE
```

THEY HAVE GIVEN THE INPUT. I NEED TO WRITE A CODE TO BRING THE OUTPUT.

Comment: First, please turn off your Caps Lock key. Then, edit your question so that others can understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

I think this query should do:

```
select sum(a) as a, 'POSITIVE' as feedback from t where a >= 0 
union
select sum(a) as a, 'NEGATIVE' as feedback from t where a < 0
```

Comment: yeah this is working.THANKS FOR THE RESPONSE.